# 502 Bad Gateway - Meteor and nginx on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor, nginx

I have a problem installing my Meteor / NodeJS website on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS server with Nginx.

I wanted to follow the following article How To Deploy a Meteor.js Application on Ubuntu 14.04 with Nginx (Digital Ocean), as it is not up to date I also watch this one www.medium.com/@jaaaco/run-meteor-app-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-c4aa1153408a#.bn9q49h1w

**systemd :**

```html
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/dezeiraud/bundle/main.js
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=dezeiraud
User=dezeiraud
Group=dezeiraud
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
Environment=PWD=/home/dezeiraud
Environment=PORT=8080
Environment=HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT=1
Environment=ROOT_URL=http://dezeiraud.com
Environment='METEOR_SETTINGS={"someSetting": "someValue"}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It looks to work well (see image below).

[systemclt status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LMlI.png)

**Ngnix :**

```html
server_tokens off; # for security-by-obscurity: stop displaying nginx version

# we're in the http context here
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

# the Meteor / Node.js app server
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dezeiraud.com;

  access_log /etc/nginx/logs/dezeiraud.access;
  error_log /etc/nginx/logs/dezeiraud.error error;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  
    proxy_set_header Host $host;  
    proxy_http_version 1.1;  

    # WebSocket proxying 
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  }
}
```

And here the configuration of nginx. The error file contains the following text :

> failed (111: Connection refused)

[nginx error file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGPw6.png)

It's going to be several hours since I'm looking for a solution, and my research on the internet is not conclusive ... I guess the error is absurd but I can not find it.

Thank you for your time. Best Regards.
(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it had to do with the port on which meteor was running, so i changed the port from 8080 to 3000 (3000 was the port meteor runs on by default i believe)

in **systemmd** file

```
Environment=PORT=3000
```

and in **nginx** file

```
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
     # ........ continue with rest 
     # ........ continue with rest
  }
```

you can find if anything is running in port 8080 with this command

```
sudo netstat -peant | grep ":8080 "
```